# Vulkan swap chain, can we reuse the same render pass for every frame?

Tags: rendering, vulkan, framebuffer

My question is in the title.

The swap chain need multiple images and I understand why, so it seems logical to have the same image views amount because they are like a pointer to these. And finally, I understand why it needs multiple framebuffers, because you attach image views to these.

But, the framebuffer needs a render pass handle. But there is no direct link on an image or an image view in a render pass, it only describe with what the rendering will be done.

Then a graphics pipeline only needs a render pass handle. And finally the vkCmdBeginRenderPass() function specifies separately which framebuffer and which render pass it will use.

So why sometimes I saw multiple render passes within a swap chain ? It forces to have a graphics pipeline for each frame which are totally the same.

Comment: "*So why sometimes I saw multiple render passes within a swap chain?*" And what was the code in question trying to accomplish? Also, render passes have no relation to a swapchain, so what do you mean by "within a swapchain"?

Comment: I mean, you can reuse the same render pass for the whole program if you want. I cannot comment on things you "sometimes see". Especially if I don't see them too. Also as commented above render pass is not something tht ever is "within a swap chain", so I don't know what that means.

Comment: I think I kept a strong relationship between a renderpass and the swapchain or a render target in my mind. It must came from basic tutorials where all vulkan code were put in the same place and lead me to some confusions. But in a other way, I think I progress, because I really had a problem to understand the render pass.

Comment: By "within the swap chain", I meant the code which build the swap chain.

Comment: OK, should probably be decoupled. Has nothing to do with a swapchain, and is one of the easiest objects to decouple from everything. If we are speaking basic tutorials, it can basically be a constant  object created at program startup and never changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the same renderpass every frame (and I suggest you do, for most applications).
You may want multiple renderpasses, for example if you want to apply post-processing effects onto a rendered image, but they would still be reused, in that case it would work like this, every frame:

```
Begin renderpass 1.
    Draw some thing(s).
End renderpass 1.
Begin renderpass 2.
    Draw some thing(s), possibly using attachments from 1st pass.
End renderpass 2.
Present to screen.
Repeat for next frame.
```